# arXiv's TeX processing has failed to process your source

Tags: arxiv

I am getting this message when I submit my overleaf file to arXiv even though overleaf doesn't have any kinds of errors or warnings!

```
arXiv's automated TeX processing has failed to process your source
```

these are the packages I am using

```
\documentclass[5p,preprint]{elsarticle}

\journal{Energy}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\hypersetup{pdfauthor=whatever}
\hbadness=6000
\overfullrule=1pt
\hfuzz=2pt
\pdfoutput=1
```

Error

```
! LaTeX Error: File `xurl.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

l.7 \usepackage
{hyperref}^^M
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.spl' (1599425496 >= 1599425496)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running htex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3355830/ && tex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./main.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[5p,preprint]{elsarticle}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[5p,preprint]{elsarticle}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: tex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2016/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3355830/ && tex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2016) (preloaded format=tex)
(./main.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[5p,preprint]{elsarticle}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[5p,preprint]{elsarticle}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: tex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'main.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process
```

:

Comment: Did you check the log file that arXiv provides? If yes, what does the log say? From https://arxiv.org/help/submit_tex: "If your submission does not TeX properly, you will receive the log from our auto-TeXing script at the Process step. The information contained in this complete log should be sufficient to identify the problem, so examine it carefully; check the end of the log for TeX errors."

Comment: @Marijn, I updated the question and added the error

Comment: According to the log, arXiv does not have `xurl`, which was added in 2017.

Comment: @soooleh To solve the problem you can try to include `xurl.sty` in you submission using  `filecontents` and see if this does the job.`